# Replace all input fields in form with select - keeping the original name attribute of each element with jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form with some inputs like this:

```
<div id="buttons">
  <label>Quantity:</label>
  <input name="quantity_1"  type="text" value="1" />
  <input name="quantity_2"  type="text" value="1" />
  <input type="submit" name="Add" value="Add" id="Add" />
</div>
```

And a working jquery script, that transforms all these inputs to selects:

```
$('[name^="quantity_"]').replaceWith('<select name="quantity">' +
        '<option value="1">1</option>' +
        '<option value="2">2</option>' +
        '<option value="3">3</option>' +
        '<option value="4">4</option>' +
        '<option value="5">5</option>' +
        '</select>');
```

But as you can see, it will replace all names attribute to "quantity" instead of "quantity_1", "quantity_2" and so on (i have not two, but many of them). What i can add to this code, to make it work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $('[name^="quantity"]').each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).replaceWith("<select name='quantity_" + (i + 1) + "'><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option></select>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttons">
  <label>Quantity:</label>
  <input name="quantity_1" type="text" value="1" />
  <input name="quantity_2" type="text" value="1" />
  <input type="submit" name="Add" value="Add" id="Add" />
</div>
```

You need to perform the action on each element, so use `.each()`.

See More: https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your example will work correctly if i have name attributes like quantity_1, quantity_2, quantity_3, quantity_4, so exactly incremented. But in my case there can be a situation when there will be such name attributes - quantity_1, than quantity_3 (missing quantity_2), than quantity_6, so, not exactly incrementation. Even quantity_6 can go before quantity_4. So what can be a better variant of code?

Comment: So i modified your suggestion, now the problem is solved, many thanks, man

Answer (score 0):

So, yes, many thanks to Twisty, with a little change i finally got the right version:

```
$(function() {
  $('input[name^="quantity"]').each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).replaceWith("<select name='quantity_" + ($(el).attr('name').replace("quantity_", "")) + "'><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option></select>");
  });
});
```

Hope it will also help someone in future!